# How to call endless python script from NodeJS

Tags: python, node.js, shell

I have a python script:

```
//test.py

import psutil

while True:
    result = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)
    print(result)
```

and then nodejs code:

```
//test.js
    var PythonShell = require('python-shell')
    pyshell = new PythonShell('test.py')
    pyshell.on('message', function(message) {
        console.log(message)
    })
```

nothing happened when I executing node script. Please help me how to get data per second (like "real-time") from endless python code from Node and loggging it to console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flush STDOUT:

```
#test.py

import psutil
import sys

while True:
    result = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)
    print(result)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

It looks like it's a common issue with the python-shell npm package - https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell/issues/81